# Can't figure out how to design elements for iPad Air

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, size-classes

Working with xCode 9 and I don't understand why everything is so zoomed in on the iPad Air simulator (iOS 11.4). I thought the size class was regular/regular, but iPad air looks completely different than iPad Pro (which looks correct--albeit spaced apart)

Furthermore, I don't see any preview for what to expect on an iPad air screen in storyboard or Preview. Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Ya may wanna take a look at https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/ iPad kind of behaves differently for multitasking configurations

[image]